# Change FROM or OUT ... to

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition should I use in the sentense like the following?

> I changed isolation level ... A to B.

Is should be OUT or FROM?

> I changed isolation level out A to B.
>
> I changed isolation level from A to B.

Which option is correct?

Answer (score 4):

*From* would be the most accurate.

*Out* implies removal, whereas *From* implies a change of state (from A to B).

You're also missing a *the* in front of *isolation*. A better sentence could be:

> I changed the isolation level from A to B.